# Каким  способом  образованы  слова?

Tags: словообразование

Каким  способом  образованы  слова: конькобежец,добропорядочность,пешеход,громкоговоритель,обновление,подружиться,безнравственный,рассказ

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемая АНТОНИНА, здравствуйте. Данные слова образованы не одним способом. Какие способы образования слов известны Вам?